# How to load more pages data from JSON in Android?

Tags: android, json

I want develop android application for one website! in this site ever pages show 10 posts, and other posts go to pages. I can just show 10 posts (page 1), and ***i want when scroll down, show more post on the following pages will display the 10 entries***.
For show posts, i use `RecyclerView` component.

**Json (from site) :**

```
{
    "status": "ok",
    "count": 10,
    "count_total": 13,
    "pages": 2,
    "posts": [{
        "id": 88,
        "type": "post",
        "slug": "%d8%b1%d9%81%d8%b1%d8%b4-%da%a9%d9%86",
        "url": "http:\/\/tellfa.com\/tafrihgah\/?p=88",
        "status": "publish",
        "title": "\u0631\u0641\u0631\u0634 \u06a9\u0646",
        "title_plain": "\u0631\u0641\u0631\u0634 \u06a9\u0646",
        "content": "<p>\u0644\u0627\u0645\u0635\u0628 \u0631\u0641\u0631\u0634 \u06a9\u0646 \u062f\u06cc\u06af\u0647\u060c \u0686\u062a\u0647 \u0622\u062e\u0647 <img src=\"http:\/\/tellfa.com\/tafrihgah\/wp-includes\/images\/smilies\/frownie.png\" alt=\":(\" class=\"wp-smiley\" style=\"height: 1em; max-height: 1em;\" \/><\/p>\n",
        "excerpt": "<p>\u0644\u0627\u0645\u0635\u0628 \u0631\u0641\u0631\u0634 \u06a9\u0646 \u062f\u06cc\u06af\u0647\u060c \u0686\u062a\u0647 \u0622\u062e\u0647 <\/p>\n",
        "date": "2016-04-20 15:31:55",
        "modified": "2016-04-20 15:31:55",
        "categories": [{
            "id": 1,
            "slug": "%d8%af%d8%b3%d8%aa%d9%87%e2%80%8c%d8%a8%d9%86%d8%af%db%8c-%d9%86%d8%b4%d8%af%d9%87",
            "title": "\u062f\u0633\u062a\u0647\u200c\u0628\u0646\u062f\u06cc \u0646\u0634\u062f\u0647",
            "description": "",
            "parent": 0,
            "post_count": 10
        }],
        "tags": [],
        "author": {
            "id": 1,
            "slug": "tellfa",
            "name": "\u0645\u062d\u0645\u062f",
            "first_name": "",
            "last_name": "",
            "nickname": "\u0645\u062d\u0645\u062f",
            "url": "http:\/\/codesaz.com",
            "description": "\u0627\u06cc\u0646 \u0632\u0646\u062f\u06af\u06cc \u0646\u0627\u0645\u0647 \u0645\u0646 \u0627\u0633\u062a",
            "avatar": "76"
        },
        "comments": [],
        "attachments": [],
        "comment_count": 0,
        "comment_status": "open",
        "thumbnail": "http:\/\/tellfa.com\/tafrihgah\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/04\/Beautiful-Mix-HD-Wallpaper-06-p30download.com-064-150x150.jpg",
        "custom_fields": {},
        "thumbnail_size": "thumbnail",
        "thumbnail_images": {
            "full": {
                "url": "http:\/\/tellfa.com\/tafrihgah\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/04\/Beautiful-Mix-HD-Wallpaper-06-p30download.com-064.jpg",
                "width": 1920,
                "height": 1200
            },
            "thumbnail": {
                "url": "http:\/\/tellfa.com\/tafrihgah\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/04\/Beautiful-Mix-HD-Wallpaper-06-p30download.com-064-150x150.jpg",
                "width": 150,
                "height": 150
            },
            "medium": {
                "url": "http:\/\/tellfa.com\/tafrihgah\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/04\/Beautiful-Mix-HD-Wallpaper-06-p30download.com-064-300x188.jpg",
                "width": 300,
                "height": 188
            }
        }
    }, {
        "id": 85,
        "type": "post",
        "slug": "%d8%b9%d9%86%d9%88%d8%a7%d9%86-%d8%b3%d9%88%d9%85-%d8%a8%d8%b1%d8%a7%db%8c-%d8%b1%d9%81%d8%b1%d8%b4",
        "url": "http:\/\/tellfa.com\/tafrihgah\/?p=85",
        "status": "publish",
        "title": "\u0639\u0646\u0648\u0627\u0646 \u0633\u0648\u0645 \u0628\u0631\u0627\u06cc \u0631\u0641\u0631\u0634",
        "title_plain": "\u0639\u0646\u0648\u0627\u0646 \u0633\u0648\u0645 \u0628\u0631\u0627\u06cc \u0631\u0641\u0631\u0634",
        "content": "<p>\u062f\u06cc\u06af\u0647 \u0639\u0635\u0628\u0627\u0646\u06cc \u0634\u062f\u0645\u060c \u0686\u0631\u0627 \u0631\u0641\u0631\u0634 \u0646\u0645\u06cc\u06a9\u0646\u0647! :@<\/p>\n",
        "excerpt": "<p>\u062f\u06cc\u06af\u0647 \u0639\u0635\u0628\u0627\u0646\u06cc \u0634\u062f\u0645\u060c \u0686\u0631\u0627 \u0631\u0641\u0631\u0634 \u0646\u0645\u06cc\u06a9\u0646\u0647! :@<\/p>\n",
        "date": "2016-04-20 15:02:26",
        "modified": "2016-04-20 15:02:26",
        "categories": [{
            "id": 1,
            "slug": "%d8%af%d8%b3%d8%aa%d9%87%e2%80%8c%d8%a8%d9%86%d8%af%db%8c-%d9%86%d8%b4%d8%af%d9%87",
            "title": "\u062f\u0633\u062a\u0647\u200c\u0628\u0646\u062f\u06cc \u0646\u0634\u062f\u0647",
            "description": "",
            "parent": 0,
            "post_count": 10
        }],
        "tags": [],
        "author": {
            "id": 1,
            "slug": "tellfa",
            "name": "\u0645\u062d\u0645\u062f",
            "first_name": "",
            "last_name": "",
            "nickname": "\u0645\u062d\u0645\u062f",
            "url": "http:\/\/codesaz.com",
            "description": "\u0627\u06cc\u0646 \u0632\u0646\u062f\u06af\u06cc \u0646\u0627\u0645\u0647 \u0645\u0646 \u0627\u0633\u062a",
            "avatar": "76"
        },
        "comments": [],
        "attachments": [{
            "id": 86,
            "url": "http:\/\/tellfa.com\/tafrihgah\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/04\/WallpapersMania_vol119-024.jpg",
            "slug": "wallpapersmania_vol119-024",
            "title": "[WallpapersMania]_vol119-024",
            "description": "",
            "caption": "",
            "parent": 85,
            "mime_type": "image\/jpeg",
            "images": {
                "full": {
                    "url": "http:\/\/tellfa.com\/tafrihgah\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/04\/WallpapersMania_vol119-024.jpg",
                    "width": 1680,
                    "height": 1050
                },
                "thumbnail": {
                    "url": "http:\/\/tellfa.com\/tafrihgah\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/04\/WallpapersMania_vol119-024-150x150.jpg",
                    "width": 150,
                    "height": 150
                },
                "medium": {
                    "url": "http:\/\/tellfa.com\/tafrihgah\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/04\/WallpapersMania_vol119-024-300x188.jpg",
                    "width": 300,
                    "height": 188
                },
                "martial-frontpage-blog": {
                    "url": "http:\/\/tellfa.com\/tafrihgah\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/04\/WallpapersMania_vol119-024-771x376.jpg",
                    "width": 771,
                    "height": 376
                },
                "martial-blog-profile": {
                    "url": "http:\/\/tellfa.com\/tafrihgah\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/04\/WallpapersMania_vol119-024-371x267.jpg",
                    "width": 371,
                    "height": 267
                },
                "martial-blog-profile-thumb": {
                    "url": "http:\/\/tellfa.com\/tafrihgah\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/04\/WallpapersMania_vol119-024-74x67.jpg",
                    "width": 74,
                    "height": 67
                }
            }
        }],
        "comment_count": 0,
        "comment_status": "open",
        "thumbnail": "http:\/\/tellfa.com\/tafrihgah\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/04\/WallpapersMania_vol119-024-150x150.jpg",
        "custom_fields": {},
        "thumbnail_size": "thumbnail",
        "thumbnail_images": {
            "full": {
                "url": "http:\/\/tellfa.com\/tafrihgah\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/04\/WallpapersMania_vol119-024.jpg",
                "width": 1680,
                "height": 1050
            },
            "thumbnail": {
                "url": "http:\/\/tellfa.com\/tafrihgah\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/04\/WallpapersMania_vol119-024-150x150.jpg",
                "width": 150,
                "height": 150
            },
            "medium": {
                "url": "http:\/\/tellfa.com\/tafrihgah\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/04\/WallpapersMania_vol119-024-300x188.jpg",
                "width": 300,
                "height": 188
            },
            "martial-frontpage-blog": {
                "url": "http:\/\/tellfa.com\/tafrihgah\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/04\/WallpapersMania_vol119-024-771x376.jpg",
                "width": 771,
                "height": 376
            },
            "martial-blog-profile": {
                "url": "http:\/\/tellfa.com\/tafrihgah\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/04\/WallpapersMania_vol119-024-371x267.jpg",
                "width": 371,
                "height": 267
            },
            "martial-blog-profile-thumb": {
                "url": "http:\/\/tellfa.com\/tafrihgah\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/04\/WallpapersMania_vol119-024-74x67.jpg",
                "width": 74,
                "height": 67
            }
        }
    }, {
        "id": 81,
        "type": "post",
        "slug": "%d8%b9%d9%86%d9%88%d8%a7%d9%86-%d8%af%d9%88%d9%85",
        "url": "http:\/\/tellfa.com\/tafrihgah\/?p=81",
        "status": "publish",
        "title": "\u0639\u0646\u0648\u0627\u0646 \u062f\u0648\u0645",
        "title_plain": "\u0639\u0646\u0648\u0627\u0646 \u062f\u0648\u0645",
        "content": "<p>\u0627\u06cc\u0646 \u0627\u062f\u0627\u0645\u0647 \u0645\u0637\u0644\u0628 \u0639\u0646\u0648\u0627\u0646 \u062f\u0648\u0645\u0647 \u062f\u06cc\u06af\u0647 \ud83d\ude00<\/p>\n",
        "excerpt": "<p>\u0627\u06cc\u0646 \u0627\u062f\u0627\u0645\u0647 \u0645\u0637\u0644\u0628 \u0639\u0646\u0648\u0627\u0646 \u062f\u0648\u0645\u0647 \u062f\u06cc\u06af\u0647 \ud83d\ude00<\/p>\n",
        "date": "2016-04-20 14:47:52",
        "modified": "2016-04-20 14:58:07",
        "categories": [{
            "id": 1,
            "slug": "%d8%af%d8%b3%d8%aa%d9%87%e2%80%8c%d8%a8%d9%86%d8%af%db%8c-%d9%86%d8%b4%d8%af%d9%87",
            "title": "\u062f\u0633\u062a\u0647\u200c\u0628\u0646\u062f\u06cc \u0646\u0634\u062f\u0647",
            "description": "",
            "parent": 0,
            "post_count": 10
        }],
        "tags": [],
        "author": {
            "id": 1,
            "slug": "tellfa",
            "name": "\u0645\u062d\u0645\u062f",
            "first_name": "",
            "last_name": "",
            "nickname": "\u0645\u062d\u0645\u062f",
            "url": "http:\/\/codesaz.com",
            "description": "\u0627\u06cc\u0646 \u0632\u0646\u062f\u06af\u06cc \u0646\u0627\u0645\u0647 \u0645\u0646 \u0627\u0633\u062a",
            "avatar": "76"
        },
        "comments": [],
        "attachments": [{
            "id": 82,
            "url": "http:\/\/tellfa.com\/tafrihgah\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/04\/WallpapersMania_vol55-008.jpg",
            "slug": "wallpapersmania_vol55-008",
            "title": "[WallpapersMania]_vol55-008",
            "description": "",
            "caption": "",
            "parent": 81,
            "mime_type": "image\/jpeg",
            "images": {
                "full": {
                    "url": "http:\/\/tellfa.com\/tafrihgah\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/04\/WallpapersMania_vol55-008.jpg",
                    "width": 1280,
                    "height": 1024
                },
                "thumbnail": {
                    "url": "http:\/\/tellfa.com\/tafrihgah\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/04\/WallpapersMania_vol55-008-150x150.jpg",
                    "width": 150,
                    "height": 150
                },
                "medium": {
                    "url": "http:\/\/tellfa.com\/tafrihgah\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/04\/WallpapersMania_vol55-008-300x240.jpg",
                    "width": 300,
                    "height": 240
                },
                "martial-frontpage-blog": {
                    "url": "http:\/\/tellfa.com\/tafrihgah\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/04\/WallpapersMania_vol55-008-771x376.jpg",
                    "width": 771,
                    "height": 376
                },
                "martial-blog-profile": {
                    "url": "http:\/\/tellfa.com\/tafrihgah\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/04\/WallpapersMania_vol55-008-371x267.jpg",
                    "width": 371,
                    "height": 267
                },
                "martial-blog-profile-thumb": {
                    "url": "http:\/\/tellfa.com\/tafrihgah\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/04\/WallpapersMania_vol55-008-74x67.jpg",
                    "width": 74,
                    "height": 67
                }
            }
        }],
        "comment_count": 0,
        "comment_status": "open",
        "thumbnail": "http:\/\/tellfa.com\/tafrihgah\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/04\/WallpapersMania_vol55-008-150x150.jpg",
        "custom_fields": {},
        "thumbnail_size": "thumbnail",
        "thumbnail_images": {
            "full": {
                "url": "http:\/\/tellfa.com\/tafrihgah\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/04\/WallpapersMania_vol55-008.jpg",
                "width": 1280,
                "height": 1024
            },
            "thumbnail": {
                "url": "http:\/\/tellfa.com\/tafrihgah\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/04\/WallpapersMania_vol55-008-150x150.jpg",
                "width": 150,
                "height": 150
            },
            "medium": {
                "url": "http:\/\/tellfa.com\/tafrihgah\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/04\/WallpapersMania_vol55-008-300x240.jpg",
                "width": 300,
                "height": 240
            },
            "martial-frontpage-blog": {
                "url": "http:\/\/tellfa.com\/tafrihgah\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/04\/WallpapersMania_vol55-008-771x376.jpg",
                "width": 771,
                "height": 376
            },
            "martial-blog-profile": {
                "url": "http:\/\/tellfa.com\/tafrihgah\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/04\/WallpapersMania_vol55-008-371x267.jpg",
                "width": 371,
                "height": 267
            },
            "martial-blog-profile-thumb": {
                "url": "http:\/\/tellfa.com\/tafrihgah\/wp-content\/uploads\/2016\/04\/WallpapersMania_vol55-008-74x67.jpg",
                "width": 74,
                "height": 67
            }
        }
    }, {
```

**AsyncTask codes:**

```
public class MainDataInfo {
    private Context mContext;

    public void getMainDataInfo(Context context) {
        mContext = context;
        new getInfo().execute(ServerIP.getIP());
    }

    public void getMainUpdateData(){
        new getInfo().execute();
    }

    private class getInfo extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {
        EventBus bus = EventBus.getDefault();
        private String ou_response;
        private List<MainDataModel> infoModels;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            //CustomProcessDialog.createAndShow(mContext);
            infoModels = new ArrayList<>();
        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient();

            Request request = new Request.Builder()
                    .url(ServerIP.getIP())
                    .build();

            Response response;
            try {
                response = client.newCall(request).execute();
                ou_response = response.body().string();
                response.body().close();
                if (ou_response != null) {
                    try {
                        JSONObject postObj = new JSONObject(ou_response);
                        JSONArray postsArray = postObj.getJSONArray("posts");
                        infoModels = new ArrayList<>();

                        for (int i = 0; i < postsArray.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject postObject = postsArray.getJSONObject(i);
                            int id = postObject.getInt("id");
                            String title = postObject.getString("title");
                            Log.d("Data", "Post id: " + id);
                            Log.d("Data", "Post title: " + title);

                            //Use the title and id as per your requirement
                            infoModels.add(new MainDataModel(
                                    postObject.getInt("id"),
                                    postObject.getString("title"),
                                    postObject.getString("content"),
                                    postObject.getString("thumbnail")));
                        }
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return ou_response;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            //CustomProcessDialog.dissmis();
            if (result != null) {
                bus.post(infoModels);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

How can i show other pages post below the 10 post when scroll down ?
**Attention :** I am amateur developers, **Please** don't give me negative points. I really need your tutorials and guides. Thanks all <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With RecyclerView try something like this:

```
LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
.
.
.
private boolean loading = true;
int pastVisiblesItems, visibleItemCount, totalItemCount;

recyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() 
{
    @Override
    public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) 
    {
        if(dy > 0){

            visibleItemCount = layoutManager.getChildCount();
            totalItemCount = layoutManager.getItemCount();
            pastVisiblesItems = layoutManager.findFirstVisibleItemPosition();

            if (loading) 
            {
                if ( (visibleItemCount + pastVisiblesItems) >= totalItemCount) 
                {
                    loading = false;
                    //load new data
                }
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I use RecyclerView. please change this code with RecyclerView. please <3

Comment: Thank you my dear friend, thanks you very much. please write true code for this comment : `//load new data` because i don't know how to fetch post from other pages for example. i don't know how to fetch post from page 2-3 and more ...  . I beg you write this code. please <3

Comment: I don't know how is your URL to get pages, for example if your link is http://yourapiurl.com/posts?page=1, then you need to increase the page number and run the AsycnTask again with new URL.

Comment: @ada.mamad if i can sure

Comment: I want set one page and sort all posts in one page! So I'm not pagination. i want load post 10, when user scroll down load other 10 posts (just from 1 page). how can write this code and show 10 post ? thank you man

Comment: @ada.mamad but this way is not correct at all, you will hit the same link every time to load data !! .. paging exists to improve the loading time in server side. but your case you will take long time while you can do this in one request.

Comment: can you send me email address? or Skype/Gmail?Telegram id or more ... ? I have speak you around this project. please :( i really need this help

Comment: @ada.mamad u can find my twitter account on my profile